# AngularJS: Cannot read property 'myInputName' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript

AngularJS is giving me the following error:

[image: AngularJS error]

where `titleInput` is my TextBox name property:

```
@Html.TextBox("titleInput", null, new { @placeholder = @T("Message title"), @class = "form-control", ng_model = "feed.feedData().title", ng_required = "true" })
```

`FeedValidationService` method that gives me that error is:

```
public titleInputValidation(messageForm: any, isTitleInputValid: boolean): boolean {
    if (messageForm.titleInput.$valid) {
        isTitleInputValid = true;
    }
    else {
        isTitleInputValid = false;
    }

    return isTitleInputValid;
}
```

It's working and everything is OK except this error in browser. How can I get rid of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to check if **messageForm** is set.
I mean: `if (messageForm && messageForm .titleInput.$valid)` or

`if (messageForm != undefined) { 
    /*do your logic here */ 
}`

Comment: Yea! :) I forgot to check if messageForm exists. Thank You :)